# Add a right click option in windows

Tags: windows, sublimetext3

Is it possible to add an option to the list when you right-click on a file or folder in the windows file explorer? More specifically I use the Sublime text editor, and I'd like an option **"Open in Sublime"** when I right-click a folder or file.

I use Windows 10 Pro and Sublime Text 3, both up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search gives already quite precise results: [Sublime as default editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450895/sublime-as-default-editor)

You can't do right click and open a folder in Sublime but if you open Sublime you can open a folder from there. Here is the feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/113